# Как добавить на свой сайт ссылку на whatsapp?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Я новичок, хочу добавить на свой сайт кнопу ватсап, код на сайте выдает такой -

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="whatsapp"></div>
```

https://ukit.com/sites/url/astropsychologiya/pages/id/index/constructor - это сайт конструктор, не получается или какие-то еще действия необходимо выполнить?

Comment: `<a href="https://www.whatsapp.com">WhatsApp</a>`

Answer (score 3):

Из официального FAQ ([тут](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/26000030/?lang=ru))

```
<a href="https://wa.me/вашНомерБезПробеловИСкобок">WhatsApp</a>
```